# Virtualbox Internal Networking not assigning ip address

Tags: networking, kali-linux, virtualbox, dhcp

Running Kali Linux in Virtualbox. Ive set it up to use internal networking and confirm virtualbox is running DHCP server:

```
./vboxmanage list dhcpservers

NetworkName:    HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2
IP:             192.168.56.100
NetworkMask:    255.255.255.0
lowerIPAddress: 192.168.56.101
upperIPAddress: 192.168.56.254
Enabled:        Yes
```

I boot Kali linux and eth0 is up, but I dont get an ip address assigned to eth0. Here is some debug info

[image]

I know its kali specific, because if I boot a windows image with internal networking, I get an ipaddress assigned.

Comment: Found this in the manual. Might help: "If you use internal networking for a virtual network adapter of a virtual machine, use VBoxManage dhcpserver add --netname <network_name>, where <network_name> is the same network name you used with VBoxManage modifyvm <vmname> --intnet<X> <network_name>."

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed. The name of the DHCP server needs to match the name of the internal network. And yet the default name for the DHCP server when installing virtualbox is "HOST ONLY blah blah". and the default name for internal server is intnet. Unless you change the dhcp server name, it will fail on kali linux. Sounds like a bug.